# Channel Images: possible way to let client switch from Tile to Table view?

Tags: devdemon, channel-images

I'd like to be able to allow a client to switch the Channel Images channel entry screen from Table to Tile, but I don't want the client to actually have access to the field settings (to keep things simple).

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Currently you can not do this. All field specific features have to be set in the channel field settings. Sorry about that!

Comment: Hi Brad, I think that would be a good improvement if there could be a client-operated switch for tile/table view. That way, if someone is basically only dealing with images, they could do tile view, but if they then need to do categories or descriptions or whatever, they could switch to table view. By the way, CI is the bomb! Couldn't live without it.